# How to link Table dataSource and delegate outlets to UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, uistoryboard

I'm new to Swift/iOS development.

I have a `UITableView` in my `storyboard` that I want to populate with some data. In my attempt to do so, I created a class that inherits from `UITableViewController`. The implementation is not yet complete, but my understanding is that by inheriting from this class I can provide an `IBOutlet` to both `dataSource` and `delegate`.

When I try to drag the outlet into the source file, I don't get the insertion point that I got when I tested this before. See image below:
[image: No insertion line! :(]

What do I have to do to define this class as the handler for the `UITableView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your storyboard, select the `UITableView` and change this to the name of your `UITableViewController` subclass. You then do not need to do any linking stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 33):

Set your viewController to inherit from `UIViewController`, not from `UITableViewController` (It seems like your IB is set up like that).
Do not forget to set your class to `ZeroconfTableController` on the interface builder.

Than, you will be able to set the `delegate` and `datasource`. NOTE: the `delegate` and the `datasource` will not create `IBOutlet`s.

Assign the `delegate` and the `dataSource` the following way:
[image]

Also make sure, your viewController conforms to the protocols.

```
class ZeroconfTableController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Gif really helps.

Comment: Thank you so much man, this was driving me nuts. The GIF saved me!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using your own `UITableView`, inherit from `UIViewController`, not `UITableViewController`.

If however, you want to use a `UITableViewController` (which personally I don't use) in your storyboard, then do inherit from `UITableViewController`. In this case you won't have to wire up the `UITableViewDataSource` nor the `UITableViewDelegate`.