# Table view with array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am trying to complete a simple addition to a view controller in my app but its proven to be a challenge. I am trying to add essentially a to do list to this view controller. I have an array 'list' whose items should be displayed when I run the app but I get blank. I have checked for common errors such as not connecting the table view to the view controller, not having constraints on the tableview and so on. I can't see what I'm doing wrong, but hopefully a different set of eyes can point me in the proper direction. The code is below:

```
class ThirteenthViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var list = ["hero", "The Boys of Brighton Beach", "This Time is Different", "BS Book"]

@IBOutlet weak var collectionTableView: UITableView!

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return (list.count)

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

    return(cell)

}

func tableView(  tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    {

        self.list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        collectionTableView.reloadData()

    }

}


@IBAction func dismissCollection(_ sender: Any) {

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if your code is even being called and, if so, what values are being returned?

Comment: I'm sorry no. I'm still pretty new so how would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Breakpoints, print statements, something like that.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't realize that included print statements. Let me try that at least. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. The items appear at the top but for some reason the cells are very narrow. Thanks for that tip. Now I just have to figure out why the cells are so narrow :-)

Comment: Not related but `return` is **not** a function taking a parameter. Remove the parentheses e.g. `return cell`. And reuse cells with the method `dequeueReusableCell` rather than the `UITableViewCell` initializer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this two lines on your viewDidLoad function

```
self.collectionTableView.dataSource = self
self.collectionTableView.delegate = self
```

Long explanation, you have to tell the controller where you're getting the data from, so with that code you'll say the dataSource is coming from this controller and also the delegate.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dataSource to your table view in storyboard. 
This link should help you [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346078/how-to-link-table-datasource-and-delegate-outlets-to-uitableviewcontroller)