# Swift. Why doesn't work UITableView delegates?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I try to understand  very basic things.
I start to work with UITable elements and how to implement it in my code. I find a lot of easy examples with UITable delegates. But when I try to use it in my code with independent ViewController and class, UITableView delegates were never called. And I found that it's necessary to init that delegate in my class. And after that, it have worked. My question, why when I run simple examples with UITableView and without init delegate it works, but in my code I have to init it?

Example code:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addVideoTextField: UITextField!
    
    var videos: [String] = ["Facebook Interview 3",
                            "iOS Podcasts",
                            "UIButton Animations"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }
    
}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videos.count
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let videoTitle = videos[indexPath.row]
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = videoTitle
        
        return cell
    }

}
```

My code:

```
import UIKit

class LampsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var videos:[String] = ["Home", "Work", "Office"]
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
      }
        
      override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      }

}

extension LampsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videos.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let videoTitle = videos[indexPath.row]
        
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LampItem", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = videoTitle
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: is it working or not ?

Comment: In example it's working with out init delegates my work my with out init it doesn't work.

Comment: they are doing it in storyboard

Comment: How it can be done in Storyboard?

Comment: checkout my answer .. it includes giff

Comment: Done it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example you provided they connect `delegate` and `datasource` of `tableView` via `Storyboard` not from code .. thats why it confused you .. you have option .. Either you set them in `storyboard` or set them in `code` ...

this is how you can do it in `storyboard`.. `Control + drag` to controller .. you will get options to check both .. `delegate` and `dataSource`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! Now it's absolutely clear for me! I really didn't now that I can init delegate just drag and drop! You explanation so useful!

Answer (score 1):

in `viewDidLoad` you need

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `tableView`'s `dataSource` and `delegate` to `self` in the `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: You're right, but why in the first example its also works without init of delegates? I used this example.  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MC4mDQ7UqEE)

Comment: It could be because they could have connected them via a storyboard. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346078/how-to-link-table-datasource-and-delegate-outlets-to-uitableviewcontroller. Although this method is easier and will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use UITableViewController as subclass, you don't need to use the delegate because It sets the data source and the delegate of the table view to self.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller

but if you use TableView as a outlet on your ViewController in this case you must set delegate.

as Jawad wrote, you can set them through the Storyboard or in code.
example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```